# How to exclude specific api request from service worker

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

How to exclude specific api request from service worker ?

I'm using service worker with angular cli and I have some api request that I would like to exclude from service worker.

is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try to using `request` parameter in `fetch` event, then get requested url from it and set condition to proceed only if request doesn't trying to get API that you don't want to.

Comment: have a look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693093/angular-5-and-service-worker-how-to-exclude-a-particular-path-from-ngsw-config