# Angular's Service Worker prevents API to be called

Tags: angular, heroku, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, nestjs

I got an Angular app which uses API endpoints of a NestJS app.

In order to deploy the whole application to Heroku, I build Angular app and I put the content of /dist folder inside my NestJS app.

I use a Google authentication system. Basically, Angular calls an API endpoint which redirects user to Google's login screen and once done, it calls back my API which redirects back to a front URL like shown on this image:
[image: auth process]

**My issue with this is**: when I have a service worker running in my Angular app, every time I click on the "Login with Google" link, I get the following error message:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'api/auth/google' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'api/auth/google'

After this, when I try to call an API endpoint directly through my browser, like `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/albums`, I get the same error message. **But not with Postman** for example.

So **I decided to remove the service worker from the Angular part and everything works well** now. So the service worker prevents me from calling API endpoints.

How to configure it correctly to avoid this kind of problem ?

In case you need some more information, see below:

Here is my `main.ts`:

```js
async function bootstrap() {
  const configService = new ConfigService(CONFIG_SERVICE_PATH);
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const httpRef = app.get(HTTP_SERVER_REF);

  app.enableCors();

  console.log('***** NODE ENV IS: ' + process.env.NODE_ENV); // <-- returns 'production' 
  console.log('***** IS PRODUCTION ? ' + configService.get('PRODUCTION')); // <-- returns 'true'

  if (configService.get('PRODUCTION') === 'true') {
    app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '../front')); // <-- Angular folder
    app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionsFilter(httpRef));
  } else {
    app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'public'));
  }

  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || configService.get('PORT'));
}
```

My `AllExceptionsFilter`:

```js
@Catch(NotFoundException)
export class AllExceptionsFilter extends BaseExceptionFilter {
  constructor(@Inject(HTTP_SERVER_REF) applicationRef: HttpServer) {
    super(applicationRef);
  }

  /**
   * This filter will serve the correct response for a request to the API or a request to the front part.
   */
  catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse();
    const req = ctx.getRequest();

    if (req.path && req.path.startsWith('/api')) {
      super.catch(exception, host);
    } else {
      response.sendFile(resolve(__dirname, '../../front/index.html'));
    }
  }
}
```

My `LoginComponent` (Angular):

```html
<a href="{{ loginUrl }}" class="google-button">
  <span class="google-button__text">Sign in with Google</span>
```

```js
get loginUrl(): string {
  const url = environment.backendUrl + '/auth/google';
  console.log('Login url: ' + url); // <-- logs 'https://myapp.heroku.com/api/auth/google'
  return url;
}
```

Comment: See: [Angular 5 and Service Worker: How to exclude a particular path from ngsw-config.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693093/angular-5-and-service-worker-how-to-exclude-a-particular-path-from-ngsw-config)

Comment: @Robinyo worked like a charm ! Maybe you want to post this as an answer so I'm gonna be able to mark it as the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Flobesst, posted as an answer :)

Take a look at this post: [Angular 5 and Service Worker: How to exclude a particular path from ngsw-config.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693093/angular-5-and-service-worker-how-to-exclude-a-particular-path-from-ngsw-config)

Comment: The link helped me to solve my problem: I had to create a dataGroup for /api urls and disable all caching for it :)