# Angular router is catching url from iframe

Tags: angular, iframe

I have an iframe that should load external content.
The problem is that my Angular application is hosted on

```
http//mydomain
```

And the iframe loads src url is

```
http://mydomain/external
```

I really need the domains to be the same for CORS reason because I want to manipulate the iframe content.

The problem is taht Angular router catches the route and throws an error

```
Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'external'
```

I've sanitized the url of the iframe in my component with the following method

```
bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl()
```

I don't know how to bypass angular router or to load my content.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope it help.

**Html**

```
<iframe class="iframeSomeStyle" [src]="safeUrl"></iframe>
```

**Ts**

```
safeUrlCheck(url) {
    this.safeUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I've done, sorry for not having added my code, I'm going to complete my question. The problem is really that the router is cathing the url

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue using an iframe to initiate a file download. For some reason when the origins match Angular is routing the iframe URL.

I've had success setting the iframe as a sandbox:

```html
<iframe class="iframeSomeStyle" [src]="safeUrl" sandbox="allow-downloads"></iframe>
```

Unfortunately Safari is the only browser that does not support the "allow-downloads" option. So it does not work there.

#### ~~Update~~

I have since found out my issue was with the Angular Service Worker intercepting outgoing requests from my iframe. The Service Worker was responding with a cached version of my App which causes the App to load within the iframe.

The solution was [simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693093/angular-5-and-service-worker-how-to-exclude-a-particular-path-from-ngsw-config/58520498#58520498). I just need to add the `?ngsw-bypass=true` query param onto the end of the URL that I was setting as the iframe `src`. This query param bypasses the Service Worker and is correctly handled by the server instead.