# express app.get working over HTTP but not HTTPS

Tags: node.js, express

If I navigate to `http://myurl.com/test` I get back on the page `Reached me!` as I should. However, when I navigate to `https://myurl.com/test`, chrome says `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'test'`. All my `api/user` routes work perfectly on either http or https.

NOTE: When I remove the two app.use lines for Angular, /test then works on both http and https, but obviously my Angular project is then gone :/

`server.js`

```
const { mongoose } = require('./database/db');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

var userController = require('./controllers/userController');

app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, () => console.log('Server started at port : ' + port));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api/user', userController);

// here lies the client stuff!

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'clientWrapper'));

app.get('/test', (req, res)=>{
  res.send('Reached me!');
})

// This stuff has to be after the app.get stuff or it will override it!
// DOesn't work without this
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'angular')));

// doesn't let you go straight to URLS without this!
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'angular', 'index.html'));
});
```

My AWS ports
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert.pem'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/ca.pem')
};


https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

Your application is not listening to https.

Update:

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(80);

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/cert.pem'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/ca.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

Comment: Do I add this in addition to `server.listen(port, () => console.log('Server started at port : ' + port));` or does it replace it?

Comment: Yes. You have to add if you want to listen both http and https.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out and update if it works. Any idea why it works when I remove the app.use Angular lines?

Comment: Try this

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'angular', 'index.html'), function (err) {
    if (err) {
      next(err)
    } else {
      console.log('Sent: index.html')
    }

Comment: Hi @Mushariar, the .creatServer didn't fix it, unfortunately, but it seems to be working after your latest suggestion. Can you possibly explain whats happening in it?

Comment: Ah actually that didn't fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! It's related to Angular Service Workers. Solution here -> [Angular 5 and Service Worker: How to exclude a particular path from ngsw-config.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693093/angular-5-and-service-worker-how-to-exclude-a-particular-path-from-ngsw-config/47849072#47849072)