# Can not access api behind angular with browser

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an Angular app hosted in an ASP.NET Core application on IIS. I can access the API controller of the ASP.NET Core application via the http client in Angular.

I can also access them via a http client written in a C# console application.

What I can not do, is access the URL via the browser. When I enter `www.example.com/api/foo` in the browser, it will redirect me to `www.example.com` and not call the API.

I think it is because of the routes in the Angular app, but I have no clue what to change.

I also have tried to change or remove the root route

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

without any change.

Comment: are you sure IIS isn't doing the redirection?  Many people will do that to avoid 401's for bookmarks and refresh when not using hash location strategy.

Comment: Yes I am sure, because the controller exists and I can call the URL with an http client and receive the correct content

Comment: those calls aren't exactly the same as they are fetches.

Comment: I do it with the c# http client to test the reply of the server

Answer (score 0):

Ah, got it. It is the PWA functionality in my Angular App.
It was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62211717/846664).